# Resources Not Found Exception only when running on specific devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm getting a crash in the Android Studio emulator and in the Google PLay Pre-Launch checks for just oe device.

The resource listed defintely exists in my source - it is in the `drawable` folder rather than any specific dpi folder - and it is found on all other devices I've tried my app on, that is emulator devices, Pre-launch Test devices and a couple of physocal devices.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_amalfi_pro_link.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080071
```

The main differences that I can see with teh device that is failing  is that it is lower resolution - hence me checking that the vector drawables are in teh drawable folder, not a specific dpi folder.

The crashing device is also API 19 whereas the working devices are later versions. (I get a similar crash for a different resource that I haven;t fully investogated yet for API 21 in the Pre Launch teses).

Note that I have legacy support for vector drawables enabled in my `build.gradle (app)` with:

```
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
```

I have tried a clean build - no change.

I have tried invalidating caches and rebuilding - no change.

I have tried changing the drawable for something else, changing back and rebuilding - no change.

I did have the same crash with a different drawable on teh same emulator test device and replacing that drawable with a differen drawable avoided that first crash and moved me oon to this next drawable causing the crash, so it does seem to e related to specific drawables - BUT the drawable IS there and does work on other devices.

This is so frustrating, I just don't know where else to look for the issue.

Update:

Following the content below requiring clarification regarding whether the vector drawable in question is used in any other activity I tested some more.

- if I add the failing drawable to my main activity it works perfectly in my main activity but still fails to be found in the activity in which it causes the crash and still causes the crash
- I appear to have at least three vector drawables in my project that are behaving the same way, in three different activities
- if I replace the offending drawable in the crashing activity with another vector drawable (not one of the others that is causing a crash) then the activity in question does not crash.
- if I replace the offending drawable in three crashing activity with one of the other offending drawables then the activity crashes reporting that the new offending drawable cannot be found.

I have checked the drawable XML and it is identical (other than the path details) to other vector drawables I am using on this project that do not cause the crash.

Comment: Dpi not only one possible qualifier, it must exists at least in res/drawable without any qualifiers. Are you sure current resource placed in res/drawable? Also notice that vector drawables supported from API 21, if you have vector defined in xml.

Comment: Yes, definitel in `drawable` without any qualifier - all drawables are in this folder. I also have legacy vector drawable support enabled - all of my drawables are vectors in XML and every drawable in my main activity is working fine. When I switch to the activity containing this specific drawable I get the crash.

Comment: Did you want to say that specific resource used in both MainActivity and others, and in MainActivity it works fine, but doesn't works in others? Can you provide code where and how you use this specific resource?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. No the drawable that is causing the crash is only used in the crashing activity. But it works in that activity on other devices.

Comment: That IS a good point, though, that it IS a drawable that is not used in the main activity - something to investigate there.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? There should be some information in the trace besides that single line. Are you sure the vector drawable file itself is not corrupted or wrongly coded? Or maybe it is using something that's not supported in lower versions of the API? There can be so many reasons for that exception to occur.

Comment: Will post the stack trace shortly, but if it's something not supported in the lower API versions then the drawable would not work in any activity... I'll also post the drawable XML - it's really a very simple drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [release `1.1.0-alpha01` of the AndroidX AppCompat library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha01), there are "compat" attributes for compound vector drawables:

- `app:drawableTopCompat`
- `app:drawableLeftCompat`
- `app:drawableStartCompat`
- etc

You must be using `AppCompatTextView` to leverage these attributes. If your layout is inflated by a `LayoutInflater` built from an AppCompat theme, this will happen automatically when you use `<TextView>` tags. If not, you will have to explicitly specify them as `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>` tags.

Comment: Perfect! Although I found an alternative way of acheiving the same thing, this is the correct way to solve the problem I was having. (I'm actually going to stick with the `LinearLayout` workaround as in my use case it actually simplifies some other operations, but I will note this correct way for future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue.

The crash was happening wherever a vector drawable was being used in a compound drawable.

There was nothing wrong with the drawables themselves, I just moved them out of the compound drawable and into their own `ImageView` within a `LinearLayout` to recreate the same effect.

A less efficient layout, but no crashes now.